# Wikipedia All-Pages API after 30 requests returns same pages titles

Tags: python, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am want to extract all Wikipedia titles via API.Each response contains **continue** key which is used to get next logical batch,but after 30 requests **continue** key starts to repeat it mean I am receiving same pages.

I have tried the following code above and Wikipedia documentation
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Allpages

```py
def get_response(self, url):
        resp = requests.get(url=url)
        return resp.json()

appcontinue = []

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allpages&format=json&aplimit=500'
json_resp = self.get_response(url)
next_batch = json_resp["continue"]["apcontinue"]
url +='&apcontinue=' + next_batch
appcontinue.append(next_batch)

while True:
    json_resp = self.get_response(url)
    url = url.replace(next_batch, json_resp["continue"]["apcontinue"])
    next_batch = json_resp["continue"]["apcontinue"]
    appcontinue.append(next_batch)
```

I am expecting to receive more than 10000 unique **continue** keys as one response could contains max 500 Titles.
Wikipedia has 5,673,237 articles in English.

Actual response. I did more than 600 requests and there is only 30 unique **continue** keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json_resp["continue"]` contains two pairs of values, one is `apcontinue` and the other is `continue`. You should add them both to your query. See https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Continuing_queries for more details.

Also, I think it'll be easier to use the `params` parameter of `request.get` instead of manually replacing the continue values. Perhaps something like this:

```
import requests

def get_response(url, params):
    resp = requests.get(url, params)
    return resp.json()


url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allpages&format=json&aplimit=500'

params = {}
while True:
    json_resp = get_response(url, params)
    params = json_resp["continue"]
    ...
```

Comment: thanks for answer. Btw do you knwo what is the purpose of **apnamespace**?

Comment: @Grig, It determines the [namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Namespace) of pages that the **a**ll**p**age module should list.